# Subdomain vHost for nginx

Tags: nginx, vhosts

I am trying to create a subdomain vhost for nginx so that users can access another folder for the domain: sub.mydomain.com

To achieve this I tried already two things: I looked into the folder /etc/nginx/sites-enabled , edited the existing, working vHost there which redirects mydomain.com into the correct folder. Basically the short version looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/mydomain.com/public_html/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name mydomain.com;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/clashbot.org/public_html/sub;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name sub.mydomain.com;
}
```

Then I try to restart nginx with `sudo service nginx restart` which only fails when I have actually two server/vhosts defined. I tried the same in two different vhosts files, which resulted in the same behaviour. Why does it fail?

Comment: There must be only one `default_server` per IP:port. Remove `default_server` from `listen` directives in second server

Comment: FYI, `sudo nginx -t` will give you more information